# LWC - Using lwc:dom="manual" to render text with innerHTML but it does not work

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, dom, connected-callback

I'm using lwc:dom="manual" and querySelector to capture and display the text content but it does not work.

HTML code

```
<h2 class="slds-truncate" title={record.Name}>
    <a href="#" data-id={record.Id}>
        <div class="first-el" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
    </a>
</h2>
```

JS code

```
renderedCallback() {
    let firstEl = document.querySelector(".first-el");
    console.log('First El',firstEl);
    firstEl.innerHTML = '<span class="slds-truncate" data-id={record.Id}>First Element</span>';
    }
```

or

```
connectedCallback() {
    let firstEl = document.querySelector(".first-el");
    console.log('First El',firstEl);
    firstEl.innerHTML = '<span class="slds-truncate" data-id={record.Id}>First Element</span>';
    }
```

Because it needs to be rendered when the page load so I tried to do it within the `connectedCallback` and `renderedCallback` but the result returned the same. And the `record` is a public property (@api record) that is passed from Parent component. I'm not sure if this effect the error.

Log result image
[image]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can't using binding in your manual dom.

Evaluate those expressions in the javascript, then add your element.

```
let firstEl = document.querySelector(".first-el");
const html = `<span class="slds-truncate" data-id="${record.Id}">First Element</span>`
firstEl.innerHTML = html;
```

Make sure that in your full code `record.Id` is defined. Where are you getting this value from?

If `record.Id` has not been retrieved yet, consider putting the above code in the handler for your record data call.

**EDIT**
If you use case is not more complicated than this, then I'd skip manual dom altogether and just do this:

```
<a lwc:if={record.Id} href="#" data-id={record.Id}>
  <div class="first-el">
    <span class="slds-truncate" data-id={record.Id}>First Element</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

**EXTRA EDIT**

You need to make sure that rendered callback is not called in a loop.
Every time you make a change to the UI, the callback will be invoked etc...

Use a Boolean to prevent this:

```
rendered = false;
renderedCallback() {
  if(rendered){
    return;
  }
  //do other logic
}
```

Comment: Hi @Caspar Harmer, my use case is more complicated! 

I removed the ```record.Id``` to make it work so there is nothing relevant to ```record``` anymore but it even does not log ```First El``` this time.

My update code:
```firstEl.innerHTML = '<span class="slds-truncate">First Element</span>';```

Comment: you need to prevent a rendercallback loop - see my addendum